# how to show Author post type count

Tags: custom-post-types, users, author, count

I have multi author wordpress site and every author can publish posts from two different post types . i want to display author post count by post type in author.php . According to codex.wordpress i used this code: but it displays total post count instead of author post count.

```
<?php echo 'Number of posts published by user: ' . count_user_posts( $userid , "book"  ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved

```
$author_id = get_queried_object_id(); //get author id
echo 'Number of posts published by user: ' . count_user_posts( $author_id , "custom-post-type"  ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure? Look at the [code](https://wp-kama.com/function/count_user_posts) of this function (at the bottom of the page). It just retrieves the posts count for the user from the database. I think you misinterpreted your code.

Yes, it relies on [get_posts_by_author_sql()](https://wp-kama.com/function/get_posts_by_author_sql) function. But look at its code too... [6125 line](https://wp-kama.com/function/get_posts_by_author_sql#L6125). It justs adds posts types to the SQL query.

So you either misinterpreted your code (most likely), or your database structure is broken.